# Variable TaskId in workflow is empty

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, sharepoint-on-prem

I built a workflow in SP designer that assigns a task depending on some actions on a list in SharePoint.

```
then Assign a task to Current Item:Responsible user (Task outcome to Variable: Outcome1 | Task ID to Variable: TaskID1)
```

When the task is assigned, I want to send an email with a link to the task and the edit form:

```
http://myspsite/list/MyList/EditForm.aspx?ID=[%Variable:TaskID1%]
```

This gives me nothing after ?ID=

I should be able to use the variable TaskID1 in the email settings in the Assign task properties?